# Azure Storage - CloudBlob.UploadFile - how do I verify upload succeeded?

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am writing automatic tests and I need to check if the Upload succeeded.
How do I do that? How come there is no FileExist method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.exists.aspx) method for blobs have been added in the new Storage Client Library 2.0 release. Since you are using an older library version, you can instead use [FetchAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee741755.aspx). It will throw an exception if the blob does not exist.

On the other hand, as Magnus also mentioned, Upload* methods throw an exception if they do not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking file size for case that forexample connection to server was closed before completing data transfer.

```
public bool WriteDocumentStream(String documentId, Stream dataStream, long length)
{
  CloudBlobContainer container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
  CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(documentId);
  blob.UploadFromStream(dataStream);

  blob.FetchAttributes();
  bool success = blob.Properties.Length == length;
  if (!success)
    blob.Delete();

  return success;
}

//length should be like this: context.Request.ContentLength 
//(if request have ContentLength defined at headers)
```